# Authorize Azure AD application to access RateCard API

Tags: api, azure, oauth, billing

Since a change in the Azure OAuth 2, I've an error:

`The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx'.`

I've followed the [role-based assignment instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/#add-access), added a `Reader` role for my application to the `DefaultResourceGroupResource`.

[image]

I've also added an `Admin` role in the `appRoles` section of my application manifest.

[image]

And adding all possible app permissions :

[image]

To call the RateCard API, I retrieve a token :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "https://login.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx"
```

And I use it in my request :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxproviders/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'"
```

But I still have this error.

What should I do to add this authorization to my application ?

Here some screenshot of my app permissions:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a brief call with the Azure support, they tell me that this kind of permission can't be handled via the portal, it has to be done in PowerShell.

So I had to download a Windows 10 Virtual Machine to run :

Login to Azure account:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

Add permission:

```
New-AzureRMRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalName "<my-app-id>" -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/<my-subscription-id>"
```

To check if permissions are assigned correctly:

```
Get-AzurermRoleAssignment  -ServicePrincipalName "<my-app-id>"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've followed the role-based assignment instructions, added a Reader
>   role for my application to the DefaultResourceGroupResource.

Instead of giving `Reader` role permission on an individual resource group, try giving the same permission on the subscription level.

Another thing you could do is create a **custom role** in your subscription with following permissions:

```
Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard/read 
Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates/read
```

Then you can assign this custom role to your application.

Comment: I've tried to add the role for the application at the subscription level, but the result is the same

Comment: Please wait for some time. In my experience it takes a little while (usually a few minutes) for the permissions to apply.

Comment: This is totally weird! Can you please share a screenshot of permissions to your ratecard-api application?

Comment: I've updated my post and added some screenshot at the end. Is that the permission you were asking ?

Comment: Thanks but I am actually looking for a screenshot from the portal where you see roles your application is in your subscription.

Comment: I'added one more about the permission at the subscription level. Can you please tell me the path to the page you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120088/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-manuquentin).